# Javascript on button click not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have a script set up so that I can embed various Facebook Posts on a website.  The idea is, it will load a post at random, and then on button click load another.  As I am clicking the button, the previous post disappears but the new one that I have called for does not appear.

Can anyone shed any light?

Javascript:

```
var comps = new Array();

comps[0] = "\"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10151746360309352&amp;id=9212109351\"";

comps[1] = "\"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10202149995929199&amp;set=a.3217789641447.156870.1167545588&amp;type=1\"";

var firstLine = "<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>";

var secondLine = "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=";

var thirdLine = " data-width=\"550\"></div>";

var randomComp = firstLine + secondLine + comps[Math.floor(Math.random()* comps.length)] + thirdLine;

window.onload=function(){

document.getElementById('compsContainer').innerHTML = randomComp;
}

function changeComp(){

document.getElementById('compsContainer').innerHTML = randomComp;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="compsContainer">



    </div>

    <input type='button' onclick='changeComp()' value='Change Comp'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

change onlick='' to onclick='javascript:changeComp()' ?

Ok, I misunderstand you question.

try this:

```
function newFunction(){
    var comps = new Array();

    comps[0] = "\"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10151746360309352&amp;id=9212109351\"";

    comps[1] = "\"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10202149995929199&amp;set=a.3217789641447.156870.1167545588&amp;type=1\"";

    var firstLine = "<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>";

    var secondLine = "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=";

    var thirdLine = " data-width=\"550\"></div>";

    var randomComp = firstLine + secondLine + comps[Math.floor(Math.random()* comps.length)] + thirdLine;

    return randomComp;

}

window.onload=function(){

    document.getElementById('compsContainer').innerHTML = newFunction();
}




function changeComp(){



document.getElementById('compsContainer').innerHTML = newFunction();
}
```

when you call changeComp, it does not run:

```
var randomComp = firstLine + secondLine + comps[Math.floor(Math.random()* comps.length)] + thirdLine;
```

so randomComp will be empty.

(updated)

Comment: This looks like it should work, but as I am clicking the button, the current post disappears but the new one is not called.

Comment: I think in the original code, the current post disappears because the randomComp is empty. What you want to is generating another randomComp and assign to the HTML div, right? Can alert(newFunction()) or console.log(newFunction()) to check if the randomComp is still empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other buttons in the html page. Try this, it will work.

```
<input type='submit' onsubmit='changeComp()' value='Change Comp' />
```